# I'm getting error 'install_driver(Oracle) failed: Attempt to reload DBD/Oracle.pm aborted. Compilation failed in require at (eval 85) line 3

Tags: perl, oracle, cgi

I've checked evrything using bugzilla. it says ok. but still not getting script running. The server I'm trying to connect is suse Linux. Oracle 10g server. I'm running cgi script on Windows x86 PC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which perl version are you using? Did you installd the DBD::Oracle? Is this Oracle.pm exists? If yes, is this file somewhere in your @INC? regards,

Comment: I'm using ActivePerl 5.14.2 Build 1402. DBD::Oracle is installed. Oracle.pm exists. But I'm new to perl. can you tell me how do I include correct values in @INC? I found this error in PerlEx-Err-002 log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume you have oracle driver installed on the windows machine and that the env parameters in windows is setup properly for oracle_home, tns_admin and that normal net8 capibilities all work to connect to oracle without perl first via sqlplus from the oracle driver/instant client.  If not install either oracle instant client or oracle full client install.  Then configure your oracle client to properly connect to the db and test that its working.

Comment: Thanks..Oracle Data Access Component was not installed on my machine...fixed my issue.

Comment: Can you tell me what component is that? I'm having the exact same issue.